# numpy: Randomly split array into 3 not equal parts

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random

Is there anyway so I can split an array into 3 not equal parts, with no duplicates, for example

array1 = 70% of the elements of the array

array2 = 10% of the elements of the array

array3 = 20% of the elements of the array

but without taking the same element twice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with losing the original order of the array, you can simply randomly shuffle the array, and then split the array as you desire.

```
a = np.arange(100) # Example array.

split1 = int(0.7 * len(a))
split2 = int(0.8 * len(a))

np.random.shuffle(a)
p1 = a[:split1]
p2 = a[split1:split2]
p3 = a[split2:]
```

If the order of the array (let's call it `b`) must be preserved, you can do the above using `a = np.arange(len(b))`, and then:

```
np.sort(p1)
np.sort(p2)
np.sort(p3)
bp1 = b[p1]
bp2 = b[p2]
bp3 = b[p3]
```

Comment: That's a clever one! 
I actually do care about the order of the array so I'll just make a copy before.
Thank you very much!